# How to make JSON reusable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Good day!

I want to create a function wherein I need to use JSON in accessing my objects.
Sample code is as follows:

```
  var dotSlideObject1 = {
        show : 3,                           
        length: 2,  
            id: "#test"     
    }; 

  var dotSlide = var dotSlideObject1;

    function dynamicList(){
         var toShow =  dotSlide.id+dotSlide.show;
         $(toShow).show();
    }
```

I want to reuse the function dynamicList() using another object. eg.

```
 var dotSlideObject2 = {
        show : 3,                           
        length: 2,  
            id: "#huhuhu"       
    }; 

   var dotSlide = var dotSlideObject2;
```

But if i use it on the same page, how would it know which object to run?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      dynamicList();
});
```

What i want is to make the function reusable even if i used the JSON object.
How can i achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: [That **isn't** JSON.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: ah okay sorry. how should i call it? thank you

Comment: An [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arguments instead of globals.

```
function dynamicList(dotSlide){
     var toShow =  dotSlide.id+dotSlide.show;
     $(toShow).show();
}
```

and

```
dynamicList(dotSlideObject1);
```

Comment: (In response to a deleted comment). It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/rmWgt/1/).

Comment: I have function calls inside that function. And the function called also uses that OBJECT. I tried passing the object. but I am having an error: missing ] after element list.. ANy ideas?

Comment: dotSlide.dataVal.data.push({title: dotSlide.title+[i], callBack: "javascript:"+dotSlide.functionName+"("+i+","+dotSlide+");"});    IS MY CODE... where should i put the missing ]?

Comment: Umm. Why are you adding an array to the title string? Why are you trying to express a callback as a string?! Why on earth are you prefixing your callback string with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)?!